# Cryptographic signing python source

Tags: python, cryptography, docstring

If I would want cryptographic verification that some .py file has not been tampered with, I could do something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA256

Created on Sun Dec 16 18:54:40 2018

@author: Stipe G
"""

print ("awesome program not to be tempered with")

"""
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: GnuPG v2

0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ=
=0123
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----

"""
```

and run GPG against it, but I am wary of docstring processing - is there an universal way to let all docstring engines to skip these particular multi-line comments when processing?

Comment: how about having another file that verifies the hashes of your "awesome program" are what is expected?

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that I have to keep track of hashes and name of .py they relate to somewhere? I'm just liking this self-contained integrity check crypto, but yeah - that'd work too.

Comment: does GPG make it easy to get the the signature embedded in quotes like that?  I've not seen anything like that anyway!  I was thinking you needed special code to get that out and pass to GPG anyway

Comment: To tell you the truth, I was hoping someone had such mix already conceptualize, but I fail to find one - I'm not very good at designing new things. As for GPG, I just assumed it will skip whatever is before BEGIN header and after END lines - didn't even occurred to me that this could not be the case.

Comment: the only awkward part about verifying signatures is that you'll have to be careful to sign with whatever GPG will see.  i.e. you'll probably have to start the file with `"""` (and effectively have everything in quotes for the signature).  generating is equally awkward.  just having the hashes somewhere else means you won't have to fiddle with the source as much

Comment: Also beware of end-of-line comments and transfer your files as binary data. You don't want your signature to fail just because some line endings were altered. Nowadays fortunately most files are transferred in binary mode, but beware of FTP and such.

Comment: @SamMason I see your point, I can hopefully get away with fixed shebang.

Comment: the shebang and editor encoding line are fine, they'll just be ignored along with everything else before the `-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----` line.  it's just occurred to me that git can be setup to only allow signed commits.  depending on who wants to verify that they have an "official version" that might be another way to arrange things

Comment: You could also take some hints from Java's signed .jar files. These are .zip archives with a meta-folder that contains a file with just hashes over the files, and one or more signature files that signs this file with hashes. Just an idea.